# Pymongo Safe Writes is giving "bad format char passed to Py_BuildValue"

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I was trying to get the inserts to MongoDB as safe writes, and I was getting unauthorized error messages (MongoDB 2.2 & Pymongo 2.2) . After Upgrading to Pymongo 2.3, that one is gone but I'm getting another message with the following trace:

```
        MongoDB['my_collection'].save({'test' : 1111111} , safe = True)
      File "D:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 241, in save
        return self.insert(to_save, manipulate, safe, check_keys, **kwargs)
      File "D:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 315, in insert
        continue_on_error, self.__uuid_subtype), safe)
      File "D:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\connection.py", line 831, in _send_message
        rv = self.__check_response_to_last_error(response)
      File "D:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\connection.py", line 753, in __check_response_to_last_error
        response = helpers._unpack_response(response)
      File "D:\python24\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 111, in _unpack_response
        as_class, tz_aware, uuid_subtype)
    SystemError: bad format char passed to Py_BuildValue
```

If I turn the   `safe=False` everything works perfectly fine.

Any ideas about this would be helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: Created a bug tracker for this here : https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-432

Comment: This is Python2.4 specific issue. If you upgrade to 2.7 you won't have this, but if your hands are tight like mine, we should find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might have a similar experience, this is a Python **2.4.0** issue. As you can see in the MongoDB [tracking system](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-432), it would be resolved if you upgrade to Python **2.4.3** or newer.

I really appreciate the help of MongoDB people. They were very supportive and patient.